# PRBS Generator module in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

Here i am posting a snapshot of prbs

My code for prbs module is

```
-- Module Name:    prbs - Behavioral 
-- Project Name:   modulator

-- Description: 
--To make it of N bit replace existing value of N with desired value of N
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

---- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
---- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity prbs is
    Port ( pclock : in  STD_LOGIC;
            preset : IN std_logic := '0';
           prbsout : out  STD_LOGIC);
end prbs;

architecture Behavioral of prbs is

COMPONENT dff is
    PORT(
        dclock : IN std_logic;
        dreset : IN std_logic;
        din : IN std_logic ;          
        dout : OUT std_logic 
        );
    END COMPONENT;


signal dintern : std_logic_vector (4 downto 1); --Change value of N to change size of shift register
signal feedback : std_logic := '0';

begin

instdff : dff port map (pclock , preset , feedback , dintern(1));
genreg : for i in 2 to 4 generate --Change Value of N Here to generate that many instance of d flip flop
begin
instdff : dff port map ( pclock , preset , dintern(i-1) , dintern(i));
end generate genreg;

main : process(pclock)

begin
    if pclock'event and pclock = '1' then   
            if preset = '0'  then
                if dintern /= "0" then

                    feedback <= dintern(1) xor dintern(3); -- For N equals four;
                    --feedback <= dintern(4) xor dintern(5) xor dintern(6) xor dintern(8); -- For N equals eight;
                    --feedback <= dintern(11) xor dintern(13) xor dintern(14) xor dintern(16); -- For N equals sixteen;
                    --feedback <= dintern(1) xor dintern(2) xor dintern(22) xor dintern(32); -- For N equals thirty two                     

                else
                feedback <= '1';
                end if;
            end if;                                     
    end if; 
end process main;

prbsout <= dintern(4) ; --Change Value of N Here to take output to top entity 

end Behavioral;
```

In it i am instantiating a d flip flop module

d ff module code

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Module Name:    dff - Behavioral 
-- Project Name: 
-- Description: 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

---- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
---- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity dff is
    Port ( dclock : in  STD_LOGIC ;
           dreset : in  STD_LOGIC ;
           din : in  STD_LOGIC;
           dout : out  STD_LOGIC);
end dff;

architecture Behavioral of dff is

begin
process(dclock)

begin
    if dclock'event and dclock = '1' then
        if dreset = '0' then
            dout <= din;
      else
            dout <= '1';
        end if;
    end if;
end process;


end Behavioral;
```

But i am not getting desired output.
In top level entity i am getting always 1 at prbsout signal.

When i try to simulate then prbsout signal becomes undefined.

What i am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `prbs` module reset at `preset` does not apply to the `feedback` signal,
probably because the intention was to use the initial value of 0 assigned in
the declaration of the `feedback` signal.  However, since the `dff` modules
uses synchronous reset, and the `dintern` signal will be undriven `U` at start,
and since then next value for `feedback` is calculated using `dintern(1)` in an
xor, the feedback will get undefined right after start, and can't recover,
even if a lengthy reset is applied.  See waveform from ModelSim below.

[image: Before preset applied to feedback]

An immediate fix for the reset issue is to apply reset for `feedback` also in
the `main` process:

```
...
else  -- preset /= '0'
  feedback <= '0';
...
```

Now at least reset works, and can make the `prbs` generate a sequence.  See
waveform below.

[image: After preset applied to feedback]

Just a few additional comments to the code, while at it:

- Instead of `dclock'event and dclock = '1'` you can use `rising_edge(dclock)`,
  which I think must reader will find easier to understand, and it is less
  error prone
- For most tools, it is unnecessary to make a separte module just for a
  flip-flop, like the `dff` module, since the tools can infer flip-flop
  directly from the process even when advanced expressions are used for signal
  assignments are used.

**But**, I don't think the output is what you actually want.  Based on your
design, and the selected taps for the LFSR, it looks like you want to generate
maximum length LFSR sequences, that is sequences with a length of 2 ** N - 1
for a LFSR register being N bits long.

The principles of LFSR and the taps to for feedback generation is described
on Wikipedia: [Linear feedback shift
register](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register).

However, since the `feedback` signal is generated as a flip-flop, it becomes
part of the LSFR shift register, thus adds a bit to the length, but the tap
values are based on the `dintern` part of the LFSR only, the taps will be
wrong.  Selecting the wrong bits will result in a LFSR sequence that is less
than then maximum sequence, and you can also see that in the simulation output,
where the sequence is only 6 cycles long, even through the `dintern(4 downto
1)` + `feedback` together makes a 5 bit register.

So a more thorough rewrite of the `prbs` module is required, if what you want
is to generate maximum length PRBS sequences, and below is an example of how
the `prbs` module can be written:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity prbs_new is
  generic(
    BITS : natural);
  port(
    clk_i  : in  std_logic;
    rst_i  : in  std_logic;
    prbs_o : out std_logic);
end entity;


library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

architecture syn of prbs_new is

  signal lfsr : std_logic_vector(BITS downto 1);  -- Flip-flops with LFSR state

  function feedback(slv : std_logic_vector) return std_logic is  -- For maximum length LFSR generation
  begin
    case slv'length is
      when  3     => return slv( 3) xor slv( 2);
      when  4     => return slv( 4) xor slv( 3);
      when  8     => return slv( 8) xor slv( 6) xor slv( 5) xor slv(4);
      when 16     => return slv(16) xor slv(15) xor slv(13) xor slv(4);
      when 32     => return slv(32) xor slv(22) xor slv( 2) xor slv(1);
      when others => report "feedback function not defined for slv'lenght as " & integer'image(slv'length)
                     severity FAILURE;
                     return 'X';
    end case;
  end function;

begin

  process (clk_i, rst_i) is
  begin
    if rising_edge(clk_i) then
      if unsigned(lfsr) /= 0 then
        lfsr <= lfsr(lfsr'left - 1 downto lfsr'right) & feedback(lfsr);  -- Left shift with feedback in
      end if;
    end if;
    if rst_i = '1' then  -- Asynchronous reset
      lfsr <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(1, BITS));  -- Reset assigns 1 to lfsr signal
    end if;
  end process;

  prbs_o <= lfsr(BITS);  -- Drive output

end architecture;
```

Comments to ´prbs_new´ module

- Generic BITS is added so diffrent LFSR length can be made from the same code.
- Ports are named with "_i" for inputs and "_o" for outputs, since this naming
  convension is very useful when tracing signals at a toplevel with multiple
  modules.
- The VHDL standard package `ieee.numeric_std` is used instead of
  the non-standard package `ieee.std_logic_unsigned`.
- Asynchronous reset is used instead of synchronous reset and initial value in
  the signal declaration.

  - The advantage over synchronous reset is that asynchronous reset typical
    applies to a dedicated input on the flip-flops in FPGA and ASIC
    technology, and not in the potentially timing critical data path, whereby
    the design can be faster.
  - The advantage over initial value in the signal declation is that FPGA and
    ASIC technologies are more likely to be able to implement this; there are
    cases where initial values are not supported.  Also functional reset
    makes restart possible in a test bench without having to reload the
    simulator.
- There is no check for an all-0 value of the `lfsr` signal in the process,
  since the `lfsr` will never get an all-0 value if proper maximum length taps
  are used, and the `lfsr` signal is reset to a non-0 value.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are never setting your internal state (dintern) to a known value.  Since all subsequent states are calculated from your initial dintern value, they are unknown as well.  Try assigning an initial state to dintern, or fixing your preset code to actually do something when preset is high (and then assert it at the start of your testbench).